# How to achieve this shape (Twisted bottle)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can i achieve this bottle shape. I tried with the twist modifier and screw modifier both did not work for me any option or how can it work. Thanks

[image]

Comment: hello, do you have other pictures of the same bottle?

Comment: @moonboots no i just have this 1 pic

Comment: https://cad.grabcad.com/library/bottle-222 also https://bestinpackaging.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/smoothie-in-a-twisted-bottle/

Answer (score 6):

Create the untwisted shape, it looks a bit curved on its sides:

[image]

Give the object a *Lattice* modifier, create the lattice object, scale it in *Object* mode (not in *Edit* mode!) so that it contains the bottle, give it some additional horizontal edge loops, create 2 shapekeys, select the second shapekey, go in *Edit* mode, twist each of its horizontal edges:

[image]

Comment: Whenever I use a lattice deform and the lattice is pre-scaled, the model gains that scale as well when it's associated, usually wrecking the relative sizing.  Does that not happen for you?  If not, which version are you using, and/or what am I doing wrong?  Happy to get PM about it as it is somewhat off topic.

Comment: Don't scale the lattice in Edit mode, only in Object mode, it may be your problem

Comment: But the shape is circular  cylindrical shape. Its a bottle.Not a flat.

Comment: It really is that simple.  Thanks.  Well there's that mystery solved.

Comment: @atek, I'm not sure what you mean, what I said is first scale the lattice in Object mode so that it contains the bottle, then maybe create 2 shapekeys to keep a square normal shapekey, then select the second shapekey, go in Edit mode and rotate each horizontal edge loop on the Z axis

Comment: If you scale in Edit mode it will also transform the object as soon as you give it the Lattice modifier, this is not what you want, and I guess this is what you describe,

Comment: I think they mean that the base mesh (before deformation) of the bottle is not elongated along a particular axis like the mesh you showed. However I don't see the problem since your solution can be applied to any kind of shape